# next-i18next is not working with serversideprops in dynamic pages after deploying on vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel, i18next, next-i18next

I'm using [next-i18next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-i18next) module for multilingual support.

I have some static pages and dynamic pages as well. both working fine on local.

I deployed all static pages on vercel, all worked fine on vercel. But dynamic page is not working on vercel. it shows 404 page for that dynamic page.

> Below is the code of the dynamic page. (pages/test-page/[questionId].js)

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {Layout} from "@components/common";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next'
import { serverSideTranslations } from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations'
import { TestComponent } from '@components/TestComponent'

const TestPage = () => 
{
    const { t } = useTranslation('common')
    const router = useRouter()
    const {questionId} = router.query;
    const [isApiLoaded,setIsApiLoaded] = useState(false)
    
    return (
        <TestComponent 
            t={t}
            isApiLoaded={isApiLoaded}
            setIsApiLoaded={setIsApiLoaded}
        />
    )
}
TestPage.Layout = Layout

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ locale }) => ({
    props: {
        ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['home', 'common']))
    }
});

export default TestPage;
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you replicate the issue if you run the app in prod mode (`next build && next start`) locally?

Comment: i checked with next build ans next start. everything working fine there..

Answer (score 5):

Adding localePath in next-i18next.config.js did help in my case.

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    i18n: {
      defaultLocale: 'en',
      locales: ['en', 'de'],
      localePath: path.resolve('./public/locales')
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and for a temporary fix I used the `i18n` object from *next-i18next* that has a function called getResource that gets the current locale with its translations

```js
// import { i18n } from 'next-i18next';
// import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const [translation, setTranslation] = useState({});
useEffect(() => {
  const bundle = i18n.getResource(locale, 'common');
  setTranslation(bundle);
}, []);
```

And to avoid rewrite the code with the t function, you could use

```js
  // LINK https://stackoverflow.com/a/43849204/14263138
  const t = (word) => word
    .split('.')
    .reduce((p, c) => (p && p[c]) || null, translation);
```

With this applied, you don't need to use the `getServerSideProps`

Answer (score 1):

Although the post is now old, I share the solution that solved the problem in my project (focus on the addition of `localePath`):

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['en', 'it', 'de', 'es', 'fr', 'ja']
  },
  defaultNs: 'shared',
  fallbackLng: { default: ['en', 'it', 'de', 'es', 'fr', 'ja'] },
  localePath: path.resolve('./public/locales'),
};
```

I specify that `localePath` should not be included among the properties of `i18n` as indicated in another answer as doing so produces a type error.

Also make sure to use `getServerSideProps` and not `getStaticProps` on pages, for example:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ locale }) {
  return {
    props: {
      ...(await ssrTranslations(locale, ['login', 'shared'])),
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Import the serverSideTranslations

```
import { serverSideTranslations } from "next-i18next/serverSideTranslations";
```

Now from the getServerSideProps, pass the ..(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["common"])), with the props.

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetStaticProps = async ({
  locale,
  locales,
  query
}: any) => {
  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["common"])),
    }
  }
};
```

Now add your language strings inside
**/public/locales/en/common.json**

For example

```
{
  "home": {
    "Test": "Test"
  }
}
```

You can add more language strings inside the locales directory.

Restart your Next.js app. It will work.