# Translations not loading in on production with getServerSideProps and next-i18next

Tags: next.js, next-i18next

In Next.js I am using the package `next-i18next` for my translations.

All my translations are working fine and when I have a page with getServerSideProps it works on my local development server but when I push it to production with Vercel the translations on those pages are not working. On pages where I use getStaticProps it works.

FYI: I use the pages router in Next.js.

This is my getServerSideProps function:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ query, locale }) {
  const directus = await getDirectusClient()
  const { id } = query;
  const quote = await directus.items("Quotes").readOne(id, {
    fields: ["*.*"],
  });

  if (!quote) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      quote,
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["common", "nav", "portal", "footer", "configurations"])),
    },
  };
}
```

This is how I call the translations in the component

```js
const { t } = useTranslation(["portal", "configurations", "common"]);
```

I render a translation by: `<p>{ t('quote details') }</p>`

Is there anyone who recognizes this problem and knows how to solve it?

I tried it on another component that was working with getStaticProps, and changed it to getServerSideProps. I wanted to know if it was a problem with the component or not but on the component that was working before it didn't work and just rendered the name of the labels from the translations :(.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Pushed my development to Vercel and I get the same issue. I will try to figure this out and let you know if I have something. Did you fix it by any chance?

Comment: I found the solution. Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69656025/next-i18next-is-not-working-with-serversideprops-in-dynamic-pages-after-deployin.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this same issue.

The current setup instructions in README do not mention configuring `localePath` however this is required if you're using `getServerSideProps`. In [this section][1] it makes subtle reference to configuring `localePath`. If you have followed the setup instructions you will want to have something like this in `next-i18next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['en', 'de'],
  },
  localePath:
    typeof window === 'undefined'
      ? require('path').resolve('./public/locales')
      : '/public/locales',
  ns: ['common'],
}
```

Note: `localePath` is outside the `i18n` config.

Typically,
[1]: https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next#passing-other-config-options